# Can I put a Solid State Drive (SSD) in my iMac 11,1 in addition to existing drive?

Tags: ssd, mac, firewire

I have a new iMac 27" (iMac11,1) with 1TB SATA drive.

Is it possible to install a solid-state drive (SSD) into my iMac in addition to the existing SATA drive and use the SSD for startup? I do not want to replace the optical drive.

Alternatively, are there external SSD drives I could use as a startup drive via FireWire 800? Would there be any performance hit for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this iMac has only [one SATA port](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iMac-Intel-27-Inch/1236/3) (plus the optical drive port). You could, however, install the SSD internally as the boot drive, and use an external HDD enclosure (ideally with FireWire 800) for the 1TB drive.